# CSS navigation sub menu

Tags: html, css

My CSS code is not allowing the sub nav to stay open allowing the user to be able to select an option. What am i missing? I believe it is something to do with the last CSS style. As it is now it shows when you mouse over. As soon as you start to move your mouse down to select an option it disappears.

Please could someone help:

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation_bar">
    <ul>                        
        <li id=""><a href="">Home</font></a></li>                        
        <li><a href="Beauty_treatments.html">Beauty Treatments</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Manicure & Pedicure</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Gel Manicure & Pedicure</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Waxing</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Facials</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Make-up</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Eye Treatments</a></li>
            </ul> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation_bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation_bar ul li {
    float: left;
}
#navigation_bar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #222;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 36px;
    border: none;
}
#navigation_bar ul li a:hover {
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(Images/mouse_over_background.gif);
    z-index: 1;                                          
}
#navigation_bar ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
#navigation_bar ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
#navigation_bar ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you post any related Javascript from your page?

Comment: This is hard to determine without a live example to work with, but is there any possibility that your mouse has to leave the boundaries of the `a` to get to the subnav?  `:hover` only works as long as you continue to hover over the element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xfLPy/ It works fine. Although it may be different on your browser - just decrease the top and bottom padding and margins of the li elements. EDIT: yes regarding the post below this is true

Comment: You are only closing one `ul` tag.

Comment: and you're missing a `</li>`

Comment: There's also a `</font>` tag with no matching `<font>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Simple bug

Your error:

CSS:

```
#navigation_bar ul li a:hover{
        border:none;
        color:#ffffff;
        background-image:url(Images/mouse_over_background.gif);
        z-index:1;                                          
}
```

What it should be:

```
#navigation_bar ul li a:hover{
        border:none;
        color:black;
        background-image:url(Images/mouse_over_background.gif);
        z-index:1;                                          
}
```

Comment: How does changing the `color` fix this issue?

Comment: It was set to #fff which won't show up. http://jsfiddle.net/CtPcA/ Look at it with the fix.

Comment: @KevinBoucher: The real issue is whether that background image is available or not. If it's not, the hover text will appear to be invisible. I'd had assumed that the user had the image available when testing it locally, but maybe that's not the case.

Comment: Hello, I have had a look at the Fiddle and corrected the missing</li> tag. Now the code works the way im seeing not that it is working fine in the fiddle. I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CtPcA/1/. The background image is a purple block say on hover and the text then changes to white.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at the Fiddle and corrected the missing `</li>` tag. Now the code works the way im seeing not that it is working fine in the fiddle. I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CtPcA/1. The background image is a purple block say on hover and the text then changes to white