# I am unable to create a nav bar submenu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar that contains 4 menus and 1 sub menu for the first menu, however, I can not create the sub menu. This is my code so far and I'm not sure how to make the sub menu appear when I hover or even click on the first menu. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Website </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="#" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Submenu 1</li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS

```
nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #111111;
        border: solid 1px black;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ee8601;
}
.active {
    background-color: #ee8601;
}
```

Comment: you will need to use JS here for the onclick event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS navigation sub menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553962/css-navigation-sub-menu)

Comment: just use this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYxoqq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **HTML error:** `ul` is not a valid descendant of `ul` (should be inside the `li`)
2. **CSS:** set `li` to `position:relative;` in order to contain the position of the inner Sub-UL
3. **CSS (missing part):** set the Sub `ul` to `position:absolute;` and `display:none;`
4. **CSS (missing part):** On `li:hover` > `display:block;` it's child `ul` element.

<sub>***Example 1:***</sub>

### Reveal Submenu using `display: none/block`

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #111;
  /*border: solid 1px black;*/
}
nav ul li {
  /*float: left;*/
  display:inline-block; /*add istead of "float:left;" */
  vertical-align:top; /*add*/
  position:relative; /*add to contain sub ul*/
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space:nowrap; /*add*/
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li:hover > a, /* target the LI:hover, than change styles to A */
nav a.active{ /* merge together */
  background-color: #ee8601;
}

/* HIDE sub ul */
nav li ul{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
/* SHOW sub ul */
nav li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="#" href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

The above was using `display none/block`, now instead let's see how to make it more *fresh* adding some animations:

<sub>***Example 2:***</sub>

### Reveal Submenu using `visibility, opacity, transition and transform`

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #111;
}
nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li:hover > a,
nav a.active{
  background-color: #ee8601;
}
nav li ul{ /* HIDE sub ul */
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.2s;
  transform: translateY(20%);
}
nav li:hover ul{  /* SHOW sub ul */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="#" href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Hide the submenu and then show it when it's parent li is hovered.

```
nav ul li ul {
  display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
```

But you'll need to put the submenu ul inside of the li like this:

```
<li><a class="#" href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Submenu 1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/caleboleary/pen/eJOdQb